# Cordova Geolocation API not working IOS 8

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova-3, google-geolocation

Am developing a Jquery mobile application using cordova geolocation api.

Cordova : 3.6.3, 
geolocation : cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.geolocation (latest version),
jQuery Mobile : 1.4.4

Am getting exact current position using following code

```
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(drawMap,handleError, {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        maximumAge : 0,
        timeout : 60000
    });
```

Problem with watch position, its always trigger Unknown Error. The same code working fine in IOS-6

```
watchProcess = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(handleSuccess, 

    handleError, {
                enableHighAccuracy: true,
                maximumAge : 0,
                timeout : 60000
            });
switch(error.code)
    {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            alert("User did not share geolocation data");
            $(".ajax-loader").hide();
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            alert("Could not detect current position");
            $(".ajax-loader").hide();
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            alert("Retrieving position timed out, could not detect your location");
            $(".ajax-loader").hide();
            break;
        default:
            alert("Unknown Error"); // Always getting Unknown Error 
            $(".ajax-loader").hide();
            break;
    }
```

Tried adding following code in my platforms/ios/NavSustain/config.xml file but no luck

```
<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" overwrite="false"> <array> <string>Allow GPS</string> </array> </gap:config-file>
```

My config.xml file is

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.navsustain.navsustain" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">


    <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false" />
    <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value=".25" />
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
    <preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
    <preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray" />
    <preference name="GapBetweenPages" value="0" />
    <preference name="PageLength" value="0" />
    <preference name="PaginationBreakingMode" value="page" />
    <preference name="PaginationMode" value="unpaginated" />
    <feature name="LocalStorage">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocalStorage" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
    </feature>
    <name>NavSustain</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>

    <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" overwrite="false"> <array> <string>Allow GPS</string> </array> </gap:config-file>

    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <feature name="NetworkStatus">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVConnection" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Notification">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVNotification" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="SplashScreen">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
</widget>
```

Your help is much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the issue. I have update Xcode to latest version Xcode 6. Now its working fine.